# javascript regex split with space and html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a string which contains HTML. I want to split this string with a space but I don't want the HTML.

For example:

```
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php">http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php</a> some more text.
```

When slitting the string with space it cuts the anchor tag to half. I want to consider `<a>` tag or `<br>` tag as one word.

Comment: Have you tried iterating nodes within `html` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\w+|<a\s.*\/a>|(<br>|<br\s\/>|<br\/>)/g`

```js
var str = `scrambled it to make
<br> a type specimen book.
<br/> It 
<a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php">
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php
</a>
<br /> some more text.`;

console.log(str.match(/\w+|<a\s.*\/a>|(<br>|<br\s\/>|<br\/>)/g));
```